# Why does appear error on Stripe payment request button?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

Stripe payment request button for Google pay does not appear.

I need to implement payment request button for google pay in angular app.
I was implementing this regarding docs :
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button#verifying-your-domain-with-apple-pay

I'v added trusted SSL Sertificate for my app on localhost.
But still receive this issue:

```
IntegrationError: The paymentRequestButton Element is not available in the current environment.
at new t (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:10518)
at t.<anonymous> (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:94978)
at t.mount (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:24449)
```

My code :

```
this.stripe = Stripe('pk_test_key');

    this.elements = this.stripe.elements();  

    const paymentRequest = this.stripe.paymentRequest({
        country: 'US',
        currency: 'usd',
        total: {
            label: 'Demo total',
            amount: 1000,
        },
        requestPayerName: true,
        requestPayerEmail: true,
    });

 this.payServices = this.elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
        paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
});
await paymentRequest.canMakePayment()
    .then(r => {
        this.payServices.mount(this.services.nativeElement);
    })
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Expect workable button even on localhost

Comment: What was the feedback from Stripe when you ran the curl command to register your domain?  I’m almost certain it won’t let you use localhost.  That’s why the instructions say to use `ngrok` when testing locally.

Comment: I will test Google button with ngrok and will be back with feedback. About domain register it is required only for Apple pay.

Comment: ngrok didn't helped ...

Answer (score 3):

Fixed. The issue was in :

```
country: 'US',
    currency: 'usd',
```

I'v changed to:

```
 country: 'GB',
        currency: 'eur',
```

And everything works fine. Thank you!
I think there is dependency of you Stripe account country.